# Getting Next Available ID

Tags: java

I'm stuck, I don't how to do this.

I want to get the next available id.
If there is `[ID:1,ID:2,ID:3]`, `findId()` will return `4` (the next id available).

If `ID:2` is removed we get `[ID:1,ID:3]` so now it should return `2`.

Any help, please!

```
public int findId() {
   if (getAreas().isEmpty())
      return 1;
   List<Area> areas = new ArrayList<>(getAreas());
   areas.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(AutoPayArea::getId));

   for (int i = 1; i <= areas.size(); i++) {
      if (i < areas.get(i - 1).getId()) {
         return i;
      } else {
         return i + 1;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Usually there is no point in keeping IDs consecutive. As your question revales there will always be holes in your ID sequence anyway. And modern computers have enough memory to deal with large nunber types so that there is no need to restrict their lengths. Also reusing IDs can have weired seide effects when they get persisted in a database or so. Therefore you should not waist the computers CPU time for just a homeopathic improvement...

Comment: next ID, the next ID not taken

Comment: How should I do it @TimothyTruckle

Comment: Sort the `ArrayList` and take the `last entry + 1`

Comment: What you requeste? - not at all. You could easily get the next lager ID by holding them in a treeSet: `areaTreeSetSortedById.last().getId()+1` @Max604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, after all that processing, `areas.get(i-1).getId()` returns an `int` ranging from 1 to whatever, which will be equal to `i` if no ID is "missing".
So you want to return `i` if the corresponding ID is missing, or just the next ID after the last found.
If that's the case:

```
public int findId() {
   if (getAreas().isEmpty())
      return 1;
   List<Area> areas = new ArrayList<>(getAreas());
   areas.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(AutoPayArea::getId));

   for (int i = 1; i <= areas.size(); i++) {
      if (i < areas.get(i - 1).getId()) {
         return i; // "i" is missing, return that
      }
   }
   // If we haven't returned yet, it means that no ID is missing,
   // so just return the next one, which is areas.size()+1 (which just happens to be "i" again but it's out of scope now).
   return areas.size()+1;
}
```

Comment: Can't return i since it's out of the for's scope.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is that with that `if/else` you will return either `1` or `2` in the first iteration of the loop, no matter what. See the other answers for how to fix that.

However, instead of sorting and then iterating the areas, I'd just store the already taken IDs in a `Set`, then iterate possible IDs and return the first one that's not already in that set.

```
public int findId() {
    Set<Integer> ids = getAreas().stream()
            .map(Area::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
            .filter(n -> ! ids.contains(n))
            .findFirst().getAsInt();
}
```

The logic in this approach is a bit simpler and less prone to "one-off" errors, and the complexity is just O(n) instead of O(n log n) for sorting the list.

However, as pointed out in comments, reusing IDs might not be the best approach in the first place. Instead, you could just get the `max` ID (again, no need for sorting the entire list) and add one.

```
public int findId() {
    return getAreas().stream().mapToInt(Area::getId).max().orElse(0) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Most people having problems with a simple for() loop, will ignore an answer that uses Streams and Optionals, because it's probably beyond their current skill set. But I like the solution in your last paragraph. +1.

Comment: @walen OP was already using some Java 8 in the original question, so I though that should be okay. But of course, the same can be done in a few more lines using loops and conditions.

Comment: Tbh that is the reason and I hardly know what was covered, do you know any links that explain the concepts used a bit deeper, I'll tick this one instead.

Comment: @Max604 Tick whichever answer works best for you, if that's the other one, that's fine. A general introduction to Java 8 Streams would certainly be a bit broad, but you an check out StackOverflows own [documentation section on that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/topics).

Answer (score 0):

```
public int findId() {
   if (getAreas().isEmpty())
      return 1;
   List<Area> areas = new ArrayList<>(getAreas());
   areas.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(AutoPayArea::getId));

   for (int i = 0; i < areas.size(); i++) {
        if (areas.get(i).getId > (i+1)) {
            return i+1;
        }
    }
   return areas.size()+1;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Returning `areas.size()` will return the last ID in the list, not the next one, and you'd get repeated ID's.